# Expressing $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{z}{1+z})^n$ as a power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm basically given the following task:

> Express the series:
>
> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^n$$
>
> as a power series for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ where the series converges.

So, I know I need to get the above series in the form $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(z)^n$$ where the $a_n$ are constants.

I've tried my best to algebraically manipulate the summand to no success! I know that $$\frac{z}{1+z} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{z}} = \frac{1}{1-(-\frac{1}{z})} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (-1)^j\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^j$$

but plugging any of these into the summand of the given series only seems to make things worse!

I've tried to expand out the original series:

$$\sum_{n=o}^{\infty} \left(\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^n = 1 + \frac{z}{1+z} + \frac{z^2}{(1+z)^2} + \ldots $$

but I don't see a pattern.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, you could just use $\sum_0^\infty a^n = 1/(1-a)$ and then expand the resulting function. Although that results in a rather short power series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Proceeding naively,
in
$f(z)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^n
$,
we must have
$\left|\frac{z}{1+z}\right|
< 1$.

Then
$f(z)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^n
=\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{z}{1+z}}
=\dfrac{1+z}{1+z-z}
=1+z
$.

Check:

If $z=1$ then
$\frac{z}{1+z}
=\dfrac12
$
so
$f(z)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1/2)^n
=\dfrac1{1-1/2}
=2
$
and
$1+1 = 2$,
so, OK.

Answer (score 5):

You may do this:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^n = \frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{1+z}} = \frac{1+z}{1+z-z} = 1+z$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(z)= \sum _0^\infty (\frac {z}{1+z})^n = 1+ (\frac {z}{1+z}) + (\frac {z}{1+z})^2+ ...$$

We have $$f(z) = f(0) + f'(0)z + f''(0)/2 z^2 +.....$$

It is easy to see that  $$f(0)=1, f'(0)=1, f''(0)=0,  f'''(0) =0,...$$

Thus $$f(z) = 1+z$$

Comment: Why is it "easy to see that"?

Comment: @martycohen Term by term differentiation of power series. When you take higher 
 derivatives  and plug z=0 in it you see terms become zero at z=0.